# Rails - redirect to show page passing a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to redirect from my `currencies` controller to my `markets` controller, passing the current currency as a parameter(the market `has_many` currencies). I want to do something like this:

```
  redirect_to markets_show_url(id: @currency.market.id, currency: @currency)
```

How can this be done correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redirect_to market_url(@currency.market, currency_id: @currency.id)`

In controller of `markets`:-

```
def show
  @market = Market.find(params[:id])
  @currency = Currency.find(params[:currency_id])
end
```

As the market `has_many` currencies so, for current `currency` `currency_id` should be passed as argument to get the current currency in the `market` controller `show` action.

Comment: Sorry, actually the market `has_many` currencies. I edited again. How should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

define route in config/routes.rb

for example

```
get "markets/:id" => "markets#show", as: :markets_show
```

invoke in your controller 
`redirect_to markets_show_url(id: @currency.market.id, currency: @currency.currency_name)`

Url will be

http://example.com/markets/your_id?currency=YOUR_CURRENCY